# servicestack angular spa template

Tags: servicestack

trying to use servicestack https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/angular-lite-spa and when execute: npm run dev
got this error. Is there any way to get more informative exeption?

```
 Uncaught Error: Expected 'styles' to be an array of strings.
at assertArrayOfStrings (compiler.es5.js:3796)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNonNormalizedDirectiveMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15185)
at CompileMetadataResolver._getEntryComponentMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15903)
at compiler.es5.js:15485
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15485)
at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26826)
at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26799)
at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26728)
at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.es5.js:4536)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please review [ServiceStack's v5 changes](http://r) for info about ServiceStack's new [.NET Core Templates](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/myget-pre-release-packages-upgraded-to-v5/4749).

The templates are still being refined but I was able to download the [angular-lite-spa](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/angular-lite-spa) repo and open the **MyApp.sln** in VS.NET 2017 which fetches both the server NuGet packages and runs `npm install` to fetch all the client npm dependencies, after waiting for all npm dependencies to be installed it calls Webpack to generate automatically the `wwwrooot\index.html` page which is when you can hit **F5** to launch the Web App.

For large SPA projects npm can occaisionally have issues with loading some of its many dependencies which you can preview by looking at VS.NET's Output Window (Ctrl+Alt+O) and selecting **Bower/npm** Output Window from the dropdown. If the `index.html` was generated correctly and the Web App runs without JavaScript errors it means the project dependencies were successfully installed without issue.

The recommended way to develop with the new templates is with `npm run watch` (or run the `00-webpack-watch` gulp task in VS.NET's Task Runner) which will run a Webpack watch build to re-generate any modified assets on the server. In ServiceStack v5 there's now a built-in hot-loader in DebugMode where it will monitor the server `wwwroot` folder for any changes and reload the page.

You can still develop with `npm run dev` but this launches the Webpack Dev Server at `http://localhost:3000/` which also requires the backend .NET Core Web App running at `http://localhost:5000/`.

I've re-tested the latest [angular-lite-spa](https://github.com/NetCoreTemplates/angular-lite-spa) Project on GitHub and all tasks are running without issue including `npm run dev` which was able to reload the page with TypeScript source file changes.

If you've got JavaScript errors running the default template it's likely due to a corrupted install which you can retry by deleting the `node_modules/` folder and running `npm install` again and monitoring the console window for any issues.

Comment: Well, seed project works as it should. I need to migrate existing project using your configs and it should be trivial. But something is disturbing that executing npm run dev as you suggested runs fine without any errors but in the browser, it throws the error you can see at the top. The error itself is not very useful. Should the build check that all is fine instead of delegate this to the browser? Especially if .ts is used.

Comment: @Roman The build is handled by Webpack which transforms and packages your App’s resources which the browser loads and runs. Not sure what you mean by delegation to the browser, Webpack builds, transforms and packages your App and reports build errors, TypeScript reports static compiler and type checking errors whilst only the browser or JS test runner executes your App’s source code and can know about runtime errors. TypeScript is only 1 component in the overall Webpack build which is unrelated to this error which looks like it would be a runtime Angular compiler error.

Comment: Will this template work with lazy loaded components?

Comment: @Roman It generates separate vendor and app source files linked by a Webpacks DllReference plugin, you’ll need to modify the Webpack configuration if you want to split code across additional source files. This [article was first result](https://toddmotto.com/lazy-loading-angular-code-splitting-webpack) when I Googled it, which should cover how to configure Angular and Webpack to use Angular‘s lazy modules.